# CORS Policy blocking React.js frontend from NEXT.ts backend

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, cors

I have 2 projects open and running. My react app is on localhost:3000 where I am trying to call an API i created with next.ts that running on localhost:8080.

I'm using axios with react to call the api here:

```
 const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
      withCredentials: true,
      
      
    });
  
    const obj = {
      userEmail: userEmail,
      validationCode: "TES-TER"
    }

  
    api.post("", obj, {
      headers: {
        "Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
"Access-Control-Request-Method": "POST"
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
    });
```

My Next.ts is using app router with the api being called from app/api/ .
Here is my next.config.ts:

```
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/src/app/api",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "http://localhost:3000" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT,OPTIONS" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
                    {key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true"},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I also have a middleware.ts file in the app folder but nothing is really happening.

When I try to call api from axios i get a error stating
`localhost:8080/api/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

Comment: Use a CORS library - that can help you handle CORS in Next.js4

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work still

Comment: Drop the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header from your request (it doesn't belong there). Also, `Origin` isn't a header that a browser-based client can set.

Comment: Just tried that also. Something seems to be off with my setup but that didn't work either.

Comment: I've just noticed the error message. What is causing that redirect? What 3xx response status code is the preflight request getting?

Comment: its a 500 response code